# Manually position legend in Patchwork

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I want to position a legend (common to all plots) in a blank space in a patchwork layout.  From what I can find online I cannot manually position a legend using `legend.position` if I also use `guides="collect"` (but can use left, right etc.).

I have tried to use `l <- get.legend` and then `+ inset_element(l, 0.6, 0.6, 1, 1)` however it doesn't understand `l`.  I also tried mixing in `+ inset_element(gridExtra::tableGrob(l))` without luck.

My goal is to place the legend in the blank space.  My actual patchwork plot is more complicated but has two blank spaces I want the legend to sit in.

MWE

```
library(patchwork)    
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(mpg, disp, color = mpg)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 1')

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(gear, disp, group = gear)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 2')

p3 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(hp, wt, colour = mpg)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 3')    

design <- "
1111
223#
"    
p1 + p2 + p3  + plot_layout(guides = 'collect') + plot_layout(design=design, guides = "collect")  &
  theme(legend.position = 'right',
        legend.direction = 'vertical')
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Alter your `design` object to include a fourth element and use `guide_area()` to place the guide.

```
library(patchwork)    
library(ggplot2)

design <- "
1111
2234
"    
p1 + p2 + p3 + guide_area() + plot_layout(design=design, guides = "collect")
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way to position the legend within the guide_area()? For example, could you push it all the way to the right in this example?

Comment: Good question.  I don't know of a way to do this via the current API. I imagine it could be done by manipulating the grob or perhaps a simpler workaround would be to play with the design element ratios to insert empty space to the left of the guide. If you want a proper answer it would be best to post a new question.