# Legend overlaps the plot in patchwork when using guide_area

Tags: r, ggplot2, position, legend, patchwork

`guides = "collect"` does its job but it locates the legend in a way that it overlaps the plot. I would like it to be placed right in the middle of the empty bottom right corner, but it appears to be difficult since `theme(legend.position = c(X,Y))` does not work with `patchwork`
Illustration of the issue:
[image: Illustration of the issue]

This is the code I have for assembling 4 graphs I have using `patchwork`. Pretty sure there is a more elegant way to use `theme()` but I am quite new to `patchwork` and it worked for me so far, except for the legend positioning.

A similar issue was resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71390138/manually-position-legend-in-patchwork) but it does not seem to help in my case.

```r
#first panel
s_wpanels_final <- (dots & theme_bw() & theme(axis.title.x = 
   element_blank(), panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank())) + 

#second panel
  (g_box_tmax & theme_bw() & theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(), 
  axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(), 
  axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank(), 
  axis.title.x = element_blank(), legend.position = "none")) +

#third panel
  (g_box_t0 & theme_bw() & theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(), 
  axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(), 
  axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank(), 
  axis.title.x = element_blank(),  legend.position = "none")) +

#fourth panel
  (tmax_box & theme_bw() & theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(), 
  axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank(), 
  axis.ticks.y=element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
  legend.position = "none")) +

  guide_area()+
  plot_layout(ncol=3, guides = "collect", widths=c(6,1,1), heights=c(6,1)) & 
  theme(legend.direction = "vertical", legend.box = "horizontal")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your code. First using `+` to glue your plots together and setting `ncol=3` will place the `guide_area` in the second column of the second row. To center the legend I would suggest to use the `design` argument to specify the layout of the plot. Second, while the plot panels will adjust to the space set via the `height` and width arguments and the size of your plotting device, the legend will not, i.e. if the legend will not fit into the space given it will overlap with the surrounding panels. To fix that I would suggest to increase the widths of the second and third columns and the height of the second row. But as I said this also depends on the size of the plotting device.

Using some fake example plot based on `mtcars`(see below) let's first reproduce your issue:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)


list(
  dots,
  g_box_tmax,
  g_box_t0,
  tmax_box,
  guide_area()
) |> 
  wrap_plots() +
  plot_layout(guides = "collect", widths = c(6, 1, 1), heights = c(6, 1), ncol = 3) &
  theme(legend.direction = "vertical", legend.box = "horizontal")
```

[image]

However, specifying the layout via the `design` argument and increasing the height of the second row as well as the widths of the second and third columns works fine and centers the legend in the guide area:

```r
design <-
"
ABC           
DEE           
"

list(
  dots,
  g_box_tmax,
  g_box_t0,
  tmax_box,
  guide_area()
) |> 
  wrap_plots() +
  plot_layout(guides = "collect", widths = c(6, 1.5, 1.5), heights = c(6, 1.5), design = design) &
  theme(legend.direction = "vertical", legend.box = "horizontal")
```

[image]

**PLOTS**

```
dots <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp, color = factor(cyl), size = qsec)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank()
  )

g_box_tmax <- g_box_t0 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), hp, fill = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(), legend.position = "none"
  )

tmax_box <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, factor(cyl), fill = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "none"
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

What causes the legend box (which is too big for the plot dimension) to be positioned there, is probably some quite clever patchwork code, and is related to `guide_area` (therefore my question title edit).

The below is a slightly unsatisfactory, but effective hack to modify the position. It's a bit of a trial and error. Simply give a negative margin to the legend box to the right and it will "drag" the box accordingly.

I've removed all the `legend.position = "none"` from your plots as this is not necessary with `guides = "collect"`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(iris) + geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species, size = Petal.Length)) 
p2 <- ggplot(iris) + geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species, size = Petal.Length))
p3 <- ggplot(iris) + geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species, size = Petal.Length))
p4 <- ggplot(iris) + geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species, size = Petal.Length))

p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 +
guide_area()+
  plot_layout(ncol=3, guides = "collect", widths=c(6,1,1), heights=c(6,1)) & 
  theme(legend.direction = "vertical", legend.box = "horizontal", 
legend.box.margin = margin(r = -1, unit = "in"))
```

[image]

Comment: Used `mtcars` to create some example plots but agree that even when centered the legend is too large and we need more space to avoid the overlapping.